# Find duplicates in a Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to search a dgv for duplicates and collect the row numbers of the duplicates in a list (to show it to the user if necessary). this is my code:

```
Function Check(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
        Dim Duplicates As New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))
        For i As Integer = 1 To dgv.RowCount
            For k As Integer = 1 To dgv.RowCount
                For j As Integer = 1 To dgv.ColumnCount

                    Dim l As Integer
                    If dgv.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = dgv.Rows(k + 1).Cells(j).Value Then
                        l += l + 1

                        If l = dgv.ColumnCount Then
                            Duplicates.Add(Tuple.Create(i, k))
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next

        Return Duplicates
    End Function
```

Now I have actually two questions:

1. Since I am a beginner I would like to know if this is the best way to search for duplicats
2. I always get the error that `Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull'`. I know the error but dont know how to handle it. I tried:

   ```
           Dim l As Integer
           'DbNull - Check
           Dim first As String
           If IsDBNull(dgv.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value) Then
               first = 0
           Else
               first = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
           End If
   ```

Now I checked if `first = second` instead of `dgv.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = dgv.Rows(k + 1).Cells(j).Value` But now I have a type problem, since the db-types are Date, varchar, integer and so on and this gives me conflicts with `dim first as string`. Anyone knows a way to get rid of the error?

Additional information:
My dgv 
 - is bound to a datatable which is connected to a sql server
 - has 6 visible and 4 invisible columns

Comment: What columns do you want to compare once i know that you dont need to do all that nested looping

Comment: Another this is since you have a datatable you can filter through this.

Comment: I would like to compare column1 (Date), column2(StartTime), column3(EndTime). This are entries of a time recording table. Problem with filtering is, that it is possible that an entry appears more than 2 times. I cannot set an upper bound here. Maybe a user put the same entry 4 times... everything can happen ;)

Comment: Ok then so the situation: they can have same date,start time and end time. What is the condition; ex: they can have same date but different start time and end time OR same date, start time and end time different. You see there can be many cases; i need to know what the case is for the whole grid and i can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to be finding duplicates in the underlying data table, not the DataGridView itself.
2. Your current approach is inefficient, because it loops all other rows for every row - O(N^2). It is possible to optimize to one pass using a dictionary(of string, row).

Here is a code sample to illustrate the idea. Notice how `keyColumns` hashset is used to specify which columns should be used to determine the duplicate (also known as unique key).

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("col1")
dt.Columns.Add("col2")
dt.Columns.Add("col3")

dt.Rows.Add({"val1", "val2", "val3"})
dt.Rows.Add({"val1", "val3", "val3"})
dt.Rows.Add({"val1", "val3", "val4"})

Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of DataRow))
Dim keyColumns As New HashSet(Of String)({"col1", "col3"})

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
  Dim sbKey As New System.Text.StringBuilder
  For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
    Dim colName As String = col.ColumnName
    If Not keyColumns.Contains(colName) Then Continue For
    Dim colValue As String = dr.Field(Of String)(colName)
    sbKey.Append(colValue & "@")
  Next

  Dim key As String = sbKey.ToString
  Dim drList As List(Of DataRow) = Nothing
  If Not dict.TryGetValue(key, drList) Then
    drList = New List(Of DataRow)
    dict.Add(key, drList)
  End If

  drList.Add(dr)
Next
```

In the end, your `dict` contains a dictionary of all data rows, organized by key. Those which have 1 entry in each key do not have duplicates. Others are duplicates. You can tweak it further to find only rows which have N duplicates (N>=1), so this, for example:

```
Dim p = dict.Where(Function(x) x.Value.Count > 1)
```

Will find you the subset of all data rows, for which at least one duplicate was found, and include all conflicting ones (including the original).

Comment: There will be users entering this data in the grid itself, so checking the datatable itself wpuldnt work hes wanting to check the grid against dups from user input

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: Then he needs a [primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey(v=vs.110).aspx) set up on the datatable, which is a much easier approach.

Comment: That doesn't matter, when he clicks a button he wants to check the DataGridView for dups, not the original datatable that was bound to it. Otherwise what he would have to do, is create a new DataTable and fill it with the DataGridView data, then run your check against it.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: If the primary key is set, there is no way a duplicate record can be inserted, so users just cannot do it wrong. If OP wants to validate after several records were inserted (not to annoy users with primary key violation error), the above method would work. Just so you know, when a record is entered into a datagridview and into a datatable as a result, it does not necessarily cause a round-trip to the database. Record can be marked as [Added](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx), so that additional validation can be done before commit.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: To sum up, you don't need an additional data table for this. As a side note, if you know a better solution, feel free to post it as an answer.