# How to count duplicate characters from Datagridview into a text?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

This is how my datagridview looks like:

**ID | Name | Course|**
1   | AB   | IT   
2   | CD   | IT   
3   | EF   | CS  
4   | GH   | BA  
5   | IJ     | IT

It suppose to get the values of the duplicated strings of the column **"course"**. So, the result suppose to look like this:

(label) IT = 3(label)
(label) CS = 1(label)
(label) BA = 1(label)
(label) IST = 0(label)

Here's my code.

```
 Private Sub CounterButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CounterButton.Click

    Dim countertry As String = 0
    Dim result As String = 0
    Dim IT As Integer = 1
    Dim IST As String = 1
    Dim CS As String = 1
    Dim BA As String = 1

    For c As Integer = 0 To StudentInfoTableDataGridView.RowCount - 1

        countertry += StudentInfoTableDataGridView.Rows(c).Cells(3).Value

        ' Im so lost here

        ' If IT it will show IT = +1
        ' If IS it will show IST = +1
        ' If CS it will show CS = +1
        ' If BA it will show BA = +1

    Next
    CountText1.Text = result '(for IT)
    CountText2.Text = result '(for IST)
    CountText3.Text = result '(for CS)
    CountText4.Text = result '(for BA)

End Sub
```

Comment: how did the data get into the DGV?  Did you add rows or is there a datasource?

Comment: I just drag everything from my data source to my form.

Comment: You could use your datatable:  `Dim rows = myDataTable.Select("Country = 'IT'").Length`  when your DGV is bound to a source, you should use the datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just use Dictionary and add the item value if the current string is the same as the key.

Something like this

Private Sub CounterButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CounterButton.Click

```
Dim result As String = 0
Dim courseDict As new Dictionary<string, integer>
Dim currString As String

For c As Integer = 0 To StudentInfoTableDataGridView.RowCount - 1

    currString = StudentInfoTableDataGridView.Rows(c).Cells(3).Value

    If courseDict.ContainsKey(currString) Then
       courseDict(currString) += 1
    Else
       courseDict.Add(currString,0)
    End If


Next
CountText1.Text = currString("IT")
CountText2.Text = currString("IST")'(for IST)
CountText3.Text = currString("CS")'(for CS)
CountText4.Text = currString("BA")'(for BA)
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks Irvin. I'll try that too.

Comment: I tried these codes, but it only showed "0" in all textboxes


currString += StudentInfoTableDataGridView.Rows(c).Cells(3).Value

            If courseDict.ContainsKey(currString) Then
                courseDict(currString) += 1
            Else
                courseDict.Add(currString, 0)
            End If

        Next

        ITBox.Text = currString(IT)
        ISBox.Text = currString(IST)
        CSBox.Text = currString(CS)
        AITBox.Text = currString(BA)



    End Sub

Comment: I noticed you put this currString(IT). What is IT? shouldn't you write it like this currString("IT") ?
And it does not make sense that it returned 0 for all of them, you might need to debug the code that you made and see the value inside the dictionary collection and also the currString's value.

Comment: Hi Reu

One more thing, I noticed you wrote this  ***currString += StudentInfoTableDataGridView.Rows(c).Cells(3).Value***
This code will concatenate the string. You should remove the '+' operator from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach. It depends on how you are populating the datatable. But you could try and create a dictionary then compare the datagrid to the dictionary

[Find duplicates in a Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812024/find-duplicates-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

The following groups rows by courses and places results into labels. I have commented the code in regards to label names for this to work. Also note I created columns via the DataGridView's designer.

```
''' <summary>
''' Columns for DataGridView are defined in the IDE
''' There is one label per count where labels are named
''' Label'ss' e.g. LabelIT, LabelCS etc
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class Form1
    Private labelList As New List(Of Label)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {1, "AB", "IT"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {2, "CD", "IT"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {3, "EF", "CS"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {4, "GH", "BA"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {5, "IJ", "IT"})

        labelList = New List(Of Label) _
            From {LabelIT, LabelCS, LabelBA, LabelIST}

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim labelItem As Label = Nothing
        ' set all label text to zero in the event
        ' one or more labels are not in a grouping
        For Each lb In labelList
            lb.Text = "0"
        Next

        ' one liner to group by last column and provide count
        Dim results =
            (
                From row In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                Where Not row.IsNewRow) _
                .GroupBy(Function(row) row.Cells("CourseColumn").Value) _
                .Select(
                    Function(iGroupRow)
                        Return New With
                               {
                                   Key .Name = iGroupRow.Key,
                                       .Count = iGroupRow.Count
                               }
                    End Function)

        For Each item In results
            labelItem = labelList.Where(
                Function(lb) lb.Name.EndsWith(item.Name.ToString)
            ).FirstOrDefault

            If labelItem IsNot Nothing Then
                labelItem.Text = item.Count.ToString
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Karen. What if I'll add some information on my datagridview? Should I manually input it like "DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {6, "KL", "IT"})"?

Comment: Thanks Karen, however my form is using Add, Edit, Save for my datagridview files :(